# I am using just audio in flutter app , playing from url , after sometime on real devices, the app stops ,trying to play audio in the background

Tags: android, audio, just-audio

I am using just audio in flutter app , playing from url , after sometime on real devices, the app stops, but in simulator it works fine , how can i solve that

i tried to disable the power saving mode on real devices , but still facing same issue.

Comment: Are you trying to play audio in the background? Are you using just_audio_background? More information would be useful.

Comment: no i am not using it, should i?

Comment: There were two questions, but you only answered the second. First, can you answer the first? That is, are you trying to play audio in the background?

Comment: yes , i am trying to play audio in background but via url not ConcatenatingAudioSource

Comment: OK, "background" playback is an important requirement because you can't just play audio in the background without following certain steps to enable that special case. Would you mind editing your question to say that you are trying to play audio in the background? Once you have done that, I can then write up an answer telling you how to play audio in the background.

Comment: question changed , looking for your support . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Playing audio in the background requires that you follow special instructions which are mentioned on the README page:

> [just_audio_background](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio_background): Use this to allow your app to play audio in the background and respond to controls on the lockscreen, media notification, headset, AndroidAuto/CarPlay or smart watch.
>
> [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service): Use this if your app has more advanced background audio requirements than can be supported by just_audio_background.

Each one of those options has its own instructions. The first one is much simpler to set up to I suggest you follow the setup instructions on that page, and if you have more advanced requirements than can be supported by that, only then would I look at the second option.